# « Prouver », « démontrer » et « montrer » : contexte scientifique

Tags: usage, synonymes, mathématiques, science

> *Démontrer*/*Prouver*/*Montrer* que le rendement d'une machine thermique basée sur un cycle consistant de deux isothermes et deux
> isochores est inférieur à celui d'une machine thermique de type
> Carnot fonctionnant entre la même température basse et la même
> température haute.

Quel verbe est plus adéquat dans ce contexte ? Peut-on les employer indifféremment dans ce contexte ?

Comment: En thermo : 'rendement' au lieu d' 'efficacité'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les sens sont proches et tous peuvent être employés dans ce contexte.

Les nuances que l'on peut trouver sont:

- Démontrer: On attend la rigueur scientifique d'une démonstration;
- Prouver: On attend une preuve (irréfutable);
- Montrer: On peut éventuellement accepter une explication moins formelle.

Comment: Merci ! Juste une question : démonstration et preuve signifient-elles quelque chose différent (dans ce contexte) ?

Comment: C'est à peu près la même chose. Une démonstration est une démarche complète et générique qui s'appuie sur un enchaînement logique, une preuve est quelque chose de plus concret qui indique que l'hypothèse est vérifiée sans l'ombre d'un doute. Il me semble qu'on emploie plus souvent *preuve* aujourd'hui par influence de l'anglais *proof*.

Answer (score 2):

Complément de réponse

Je ne peux affirmer ce qui suit que dans le contexte des mathématiques ; en ce qui concerne la physique il pourrait exister des nuances bien que je doute de cela.
En général il n'est question que d'une préférence personnelle ; par ordre de formalisme croissant on trouve
« montrer » puis « démontrer » et « prouver », quoiqu'il est contestable d'affirmer que « prouver » est vraiment plus formel que « démontrer ».

Il faut savoir qu'en mathématiques une **preuve** et une **démonstration** ne sont jamais qu'une et la même chose, c'est à dire la déduction d'une assertion finale seulement à partir d'axiomes, de définitions et de théorèmes tous reconnus dans la théorie ; cette assertion finale doit découler d'une chaine d'applications des axiomes, définitions et théorèmes, dans un ordre donné qui dépend de ce que l'on prouve et tout élément de l'un de ces trois types peut être cités plusieurs fois à l'appui de nouvelles déductions amenant vers la déduction finale. Donc, « **prouver** » et « **démontrer** » signifient toujours la même chose.

Le niveau de rigueur d'une preuve, ou démonstration, n'est qu'une conséquence d'un choix que fait l'auteur de fournir plus ou moins d'information, cela selon des critères variés d'intérêt ; par exemple un chapitre de revue de notions préliminaire peut parfois être écrit avec des preuves abrégées, essentiellement parce que les étudiants n'ont besoin que d'un rappel et/ou que le détail des preuves n'est pas si important dans ce qui suivra ; il peut y avoir d'autres raisons.

Comment: Bien vu. Il faut noter que ce que demande la question citée, c'est de fournir une démonstration mathématique du résultat *en supposant vrai les hypothèses habituelles de modélisation physique des phénomènes thermodynamiques* (hypothèses au se de théorie che Popper). Ce n'est pas une *preuve* au sens strict car ces hypothèses ne sont pas, elles, prouvées. Il s'agit de *montrer* (que le résultat découle des hypothèses admises dans la théorie).

Comment: @A.G. Si les hypothèses impliquent une série de formules  et qu'il n'y a qu'à donner des valeurs numériques aux constantes et aux variables pour arriver à des données qui correspondent au résultat, il n'y a même pas besoin de parler de démonstration, le terme « vérification » est celui qui convient le mieux.

Comment: Bien d'acccord avec vous !

Answer (score 2):

En physique, on utilise 'prouver' et 'démontrer' surtout quand on fait... des maths. La question originelle étant apparemment théorique, on peut utiliser ces termes. On notera que 'montrer' n'a pas de nom et est utilisé en maths surtout dans des exercices : 'montrer que...' (tellement courant que 'Mq : ...' devient vite parfaitement compréhensible).

Si les résultats sont empiriques ou le fruit de simulations, on fera plus attention. Certaines revues interdisent d'ailleurs ce genre de vocabulaire (notamment dans les résumés). 'Montrer' étant plus faible que les deux autres on peut l'utiliser, mais un auteur qui dirait que ses résultats expérimentaux 'prouvent' quelque chose passerait pour prétentieux. (Popper est passé par là.)

Dans les 'sciences' humaines, toute assertion d'une doctrine est considérée comme preuve suffisante de sa vérité, mais c'est un autre problème.

Answer (score 2):

- Dans un contexte de physique comme celui-ci le meilleur choix est « montrer que
   » (la physique est une science *à théories*).
- Les verbes « démontrer » et « prouver » s'appliquent principalement aux
  mathématiques (science *à axiomes*). Le verbe « prouver », fort répandu aujourd'hui, est influencé par l'anglais (*prove that...*), « démontrer » lui est préférable.